# How to use Firebase authentication on a "Local hosted" web app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So, I finally got Firebase authentication working for my web app. It works when hosted on a website, but does not work when hosted locally, or when I run my app on my phone.

I receive the error "This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled."

I understand that this is caused by the page not being hosted on a web server. However, I don't understand what I need to do in order to have the authentication working on my app "locally", because even using an iframe to reference the page hosted online is not allowed.

This is my first app, help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a local web server to serve the content, **not loading HTML files directly into the browser from your filesystem**.  The URL host should be "localhost" in order to be considered locally served.

[The Firebase emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) provides a local emulator for Firebase Hosting, which serves static content.  Even if you don't want to deploy your site to Firebase Hosting, you can still serve its static content that way.

Or, use whatever local web server is provided by the web framework you're using.  Again, your browser should be pointed to something that looks like "http://localhost".  Ultimately, it's up to you to provide that locally hosted version of your site.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I understand that this would solve my issue when running it on my computer locally, but does this solution also work when running my app on my phone? I am packing the android .apk file using cordova.

Comment: I doubt it. Take a look at the firebase console in the Authentication product, and load the "Sign-in method" tab.  Scroll down to "Authorized domains".  See how it only lists localhost and other known Firebase Hosting domains? Those are probably the only sites where it will work.  I don't know what Cordova does, but it's probably not serving local content through some built-in web server.  But if it is, you'll have to figure out what the URL is and add it here.

Comment: Cordova has special instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I've been on the sites for the past few hours and totally forgot I started off with these pages, I just thought I was done when I had it working off of my website.